# Find an object by ID that has a key member only

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

Im trying to query an object by ID that dosent have an ID field.

Doing key.getId() does return a number but will not work when using

```
//will not work due to parenting object
pm.getObjectById("EventModel", 5322);

public class EventModel extends Model
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    protected Key key;
    ...
}
```

NOTE: this is object is parented by a different object

i tried to query using "key.id == idParam" and it fails because the object key is not embedded is there any way to make this work so i can query the object by id not just only the key

A workaround will be to save the an id field after the key is initiazlied and query it
but this adds 2 writes each time i create an object.

If you have any idea on how to make this work please share :)

Thanks